# Defining model methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Currently I have an Order, OrderItems and Products model. I want to define a method called subtotal in OrderItems, which will return the value of the quantity times the price (through relationship product.price).

How could I accomplish that? I dont know how to access columns and columns through a relationship.

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :product

validates :order_id, presence: true
validates :product_id, presence: true

def subtotal
    quantity * product.price
end
end
```

Table schema

```
create_table "order_items", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "product_id"
t.integer  "order_id"
t.integer  "quantity"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider post here at least the schema of `OrderItems` table.

Comment: I mean the columns of your table...

Comment: heheh sorry..now i got it

Comment: :D what happens if you try `self.quantity * self.product.price`?

Comment: That works too, the problem was being caused by some items without  quantity set.. Thank you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little unsure about the relationship between OrderItems and Products but if you've done `belongs_to: products` in your `models/OrderItems.rb`, then you can simply do `quantity * product.price`

Comment: That's what I initially did, but I got the error **undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass**..

Comment: That means the quantity is not set on your OrderItem. Might be a good idea to add a validation on `quantity` on your OrderItem model.

Something like
`validates_numericality_of :quantity, only_integer: true, greater_than: 0`

Comment: You got it! This was happening because I had some items without quantity set. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your Order model you have a relationship as follows,

```
has_many :order_items
```

Hence, if you fetch an order row from the database then, in order to calculate the total you can use the following code.

Define a method called total_price in OrderItem class.

```
def total_price

  tot_price = self.product.price * self.quantity

  tot_price
end
```

then you can call it as follows

```
order = Order.first
total_price = order.order_items.sum(&:total_price)
```